Palestinian society's commitment to civil rights for Jews
In an August 2023 interview with Bassam Jaber, on the Arabic-language channel Hala TV, Bezalel Smotrich said the following (emphasis added):

I want to say first of all, unequivocally: I as Minister of the Treasury of all the citizens of Israel, without differentiating between religion, race or gender, I feel the pain [of intra-Arab violence in the Arab sector], and I am obligated to do everything to fight this [the violence], to prevent it, and to protect the lives, peace, security, and the feeling of security, of all of Israel's citizens, among them Israel's Arab citizens; I am obligated to improve infrastructure and services, and everything the Arab citizens of Israel deserve by right, and not out of charity. I repeat -- by right, and not out of charity.

This echoes Israel's Declaration of Independence, which states unequivocally (emphasis added):

THE STATE OF ISRAEL will be open for Jewish immigration and for the Ingathering of the Exiles; it will foster the development of the country for the benefit of all its inhabitants; it will be based on freedom, justice and peace as envisaged by the prophets of Israel; it will ensure complete equality of social and political rights to all its inhabitants irrespective of religion, race or sex; it will guarantee freedom of religion, conscience, language, education and culture; it will safeguard the Holy Places of all religions; and it will be faithful to the principles of the Charter of the United Nations.
...
WE APPEAL - in the very midst of the onslaught launched against us now for months - to the Arab inhabitants of the State of Israel to preserve peace and participate in the upbuilding of the State on the basis of full and equal citizenship and due representation in all its provisional and permanent institutions.

The video was posted on the official YouTube channel of the Religious Zionism party, headed by Smotrich, suggesting (at the very least) that his constituents would see nothing wrong with this messaging.
While it's possible that Smotrich is misrepresenting his views to fool either his constituents or the Israel public (unlikely, considering how outspoken he is on other points), the flip side of that argument is there's enough political pressure on him to do so from the party or from Israeli society.
Are there any examples of Palestinian leaders or political figures willing to make credible parallel guarantees of full civil rights for Jewish citizens in a future Palestinian state, that demonstrate Palestinian society's commitment to do so?

Rashid Khalidi in The Iron Cage does speak of PLO adopting principles of democratic and secular Palestinian state, where Jews would have equal rights. I quote some of the relevant passages below, but it is necessary to keep in mind some caveats:

Khalidi's does not provide many quotes or other specific details to support his assertions, and I am having a bit of a hard time confirming them using mainstream media
There is a caveat of how many Jews could become equal citizens of the democratic and Palestinian state - e.g., some suggested limiting it to those who already resided in the future Palestinian state territory before 1948, which is an insignificant number, compared to more than half a million of Jews currently living in the West Bank and Jerusalem, who are actually concerned by this question. This number is even less meaningful, if we speak of a one-state solution (which one may also want to be secular and democratic.)


The first fresh thinking among Palestinians about the form to
be taken by a new polity in Palestine was the proposal put forward
at the end of the 1960s, following the June 1967 war, during which
Israel occupied the West Bank, Gaza Strip, and East Jerusalem, as
well as the Golan Heights and Sinai Peninsula. This proposal originated with the Democratic Front for the Liberation of Palestine
(DFLP). It was discreetly but effectively backed by leaders of the
dominant, mainstream Fateh movement, who by now had wrested
control of the PLO away from Egypt and the other Arab states that
had originally sponsored its formation. This proposal called for a single, secular, democratic state in Palestine, in which citizens of all
faiths would be equal. The democratic secular state model eventually became the official position of the PLO, although the nature of
this projected state was never fully fleshed out. Fateh leaders like
Yasser ‘Arafat and Abu Iyyad were astute in using the DFLP to float
the proposal, testing the reactions to it, and then adopting it as their
own (this was to happen again when the PLO further modified its
objectives and gradually adopted a two-state solution beginning in
the mid-1970s).
While addressing Palestinian aspirations for the “restoration”
of Arab Palestine, this new approach also postulated the equal
citizenship rights of Israeli Jews and Palestinian Arabs. In this it
marked a significant change from the provisions of the Palestinian
National Charter of 1964, and the first acceptance by Palestinians after 1948 that Israelis had full and equal political rights in Palestine
alongside Palestinian Arabs.

(These bold claims are followed by a passage describing how backward was Israeli thinking at the time, in comparison to the progressive PLO...)

However, although the secular democratic state idea explicitly
took into account Palestinian national aspirations, it did not address either implicitly or explicitly the issue of the collective or national rights of Israeli Jews, rights that official Palestinian political
rhetoric still did not recognize. In this rhetoric, Israeli Jews in Palestine were still described as members of a religious, not a national,
group, and thus were seen as having full civil, religious, and now
political, rights as individuals, but not collective national rights.
This idea, although it represented a clear advance on the backward-looking rhetoric of the original language of the Palestinian National
Charter, nevertheless represented a continued Palestinian rejection
of national rights for Jews in Palestine, and of the state of Israel
itself. In consequence, this approach ran counter to the international consensus based on UN General Assembly Resolution 181 of
November 29, 1947, which had called for the establishment of both
a Jewish and an Arab state in Palestine, and which was the international basis for the legitimacy of Israel.

PLO 1968 charter
The above claims by Khalidi are partially based on the Palestinian Liberation Organization Charter (the Charter itself can be found here):

Article 5:
The Palestinians are those Arab nationals who, until 1947, normally resided in Palestine regardless of whether they were evicted from it or have stayed there. Anyone born, after that date, of a Palestinian father - whether inside Palestine or outside it - is also a Palestinian.
Article 6:
The Jews who had normally resided in Palestine until the beginning of the Zionist invasion will be considered Palestinians.
[...]
Article 20:
The Balfour Declaration, the Mandate for Palestine, and everything that has been based upon them, are deemed null and void. Claims of historical or religious ties of Jews with Palestine are incompatible with the facts of history and the true conception of what constitutes statehood. Judaism, being a religion, is not an independent nationality. Nor do Jews constitute a single nation with an identity of its own; they are citizens of the states to which they belong.


It would be a better answer if you'd also refer to the relevant laws that the Palestinians have enacted. E.g.: the law forbidding sale of land to Jews.

@littleadv: Kind of. As long as those Jews are Israeli Jews, the Q is not quite the same as about the citizens of the same state. It's more like asking if the US allows unrestricted sales of land to Chinese citizens etc. To say nothing of the policies of more 'touchy' countries like Russia, China etc. How much land can US citizens buy there? Esp in the most 'touchy' regions like Crimea https://www.themoscowtimes.com/2021/04/01/new-crimean-land-law-banning-foreign-ownership-comes-into-force-a73443

@littleadv: didn't think the US backlash against the Chinese was so severe, BTW https://www.politico.com/news/2024/04/03/state-laws-china-land-buying-00150030

@thegodsfromengineering The PA allows land sales to Arab citizens of Israel.

@ZevSpitz: interesting. Anyhow, I was looking whether there were any Jews who claimed Palestinian citizenship. Apparently  there were some but too few for any statistics.

@ZevSpitz: aside, while everyone was fretting about Netanyahu threatening judicial independence in Israel, it looks like Abbas gave himself the power to appoint pretty much all the judges himself, or at least the heads of each branch of the PA's byzantine justice system https://ecfr.eu/special/mapping_palestinian_politics/justice_system/

@ZevSpitz TBH, I can't make heads or tails of this land thing. Some Israeli newspapers say that PA prohibits sale to Israelis (not Jews) under some inherited Jordanian laws. https://www.jpost.com/arab-israeli-conflict/pa-edict-selling-property-to-israelis-an-act-of-high-treason-569254  Separately I can confirm that Jordan, even much more recently banned sale of some lands to Israelis https://investmentpolicy.unctad.org/investment-policy-monitor/measures/2867/jordan-prohibits-the-sale-and-rent-of-properties-to-citizens-of-israel-in-the-petra-region So that pans out. But... [next comment]

@ZevSpitz You're probably right that the PA selectively enforces that, since Israeli Arabs reportedly buy property in the West Bank without much trouble. https://www.timesofisrael.com/lured-by-cheap-prices-and-luxury-digs-arab-israelis-are-snapping-up-west-bank-homes/

@ZevSpitz There's also the issue of some fatwas etc., but AFAICT the PA's Sharia courts can only issue rulings on some [civil] matters, but not others. So these PA Sharia courts can perhaps prohibit land sales to non-Muslims under some of those fatwas. Israel also recognizes Sharia courts [for Muslims] but apparently not their authority over land transfers. https://www.gov.il/en/pages/about_sharia Alas, I can't find a similar list of what PA recognizes the Sharia courts for, in precise detail.

@ZevSpitz: Anyhow, the ToI piece has some details on the 'workarounds': "On the Palestinian side, laws are in place to keep Israelis of any stripe from buying Palestinian land. To get around the rules, Arab Israelis only buy part of a property — up to 49% — or buy an apartment or condo in a development, which Palestinian authorities are sometimes willing to overlook as it is not considered the same as direct ownership of a single-family home on a plot of land."

@thegodsfromengineering I'm not entirely sure I understand your analogies. The death penalty in pa is for selling land to Jews. Not to Israelis.

@littleadv: source?

@thegodsfromengineering follow the references. As Zev Spitz pointed out - it is never enforced towards Israeli Arabs. Only Jews.

@littleadv: I did follow them, see quotes above.

Although many comments on this were deleted, the claim that Smotrich's claim is 'credible' hinges on ignoring much else he said. Or that the 'full' offer extends to Palestinians who can never return let alone be accepted as Israeli citizens. As for the Q, I don't find it terribly relevant since few Jews want to live in a Palestinian state, when they have other choices that aren't likely to be invalidated anytime soon. So the Q is interesting at a rhetorical/hypocrisy level at best.
Off the top of my head, a number of the communist-inspired Palestinian factions perhaps adopted a USSR version of rights. Broad on paper or in theory... (Wiki claims the PFLP was the 'second largest' group besides Fatah at one point.)
Purely at propaganda/rhetoric level, it doesn't take a lot find some statements paralleling Smotrich's, at least in times past. E.g.:

In spring 1969, one of the most prominent leaders of Fatah, Salah Khalaf  (Abu Iyad), emphasized the humanitarian and non-racist nature of the Palestinian revolution “by clarifying our humane attitude toward Jews as people … and persuading them that we are not really as Zionism portrays us—savages who want to massacre them and throw their women and children into the sea.” He called on Arab states to say they were willing to receive all Jews who had migrated to Palestine from Arab countries and to restore their property and their civil rights as Arab citizens in those countries on an equal footing with other Arab citizens. He said Arab states should take advantage of the contradictions within Israeli society, especially between Oriental Jews and Western Jews.
Fatah's adoption of this objective provoked rich debate in Palestinian circles, with the Popular Front for the Liberation of Palestine (PFLP) and the Democratic Front for the Liberation of Palestine
Popular Democratic Front for the Liberation of Palestine (DFLP) taking distinctive positions. In the second half of 1968, the PFLP adopted the aim of setting up “a democratic Arab state on the land of Palestine, in which the cultural and religious rights of the non-Arab communities would be preserved, including the Jewish community.” That would come about after the destruction of Israel “as an economic, political and military entity based on aggression” and the liberation of Palestine. In 1970 the front judged that the long and arduous process of liberating Palestine would be achieved by “a broad-based, socialist, progressive national liberation movement, with a base much broader than the masses of the Palestinian Arab people,” and that the state that would be set up after liberation would be “defined geographically, not by the borders of Palestine as drawn by the British Mandate, but by the borders of the socialist, progressive popular struggle movement that achieves liberation.” It said that “within this state a democratic solution to the Jewish question will be possible, and the Jews will become citizens of that state with rights equal to those of other citizens, and with the same obligations.”

The smaller DFLP (mentioned above) had a similarly generous platform, on paper, of:

“[...] setting up a popular democratic Palestinian state in which Arabs and Jews could live without discrimination, a state opposed to all forms of class oppression, with all Arabs and Jews given the right to develop their own national cultures.”   The front advocated addressing Israeli public opinion, opening a dialogue with all “progressive” Jews in Israel and the rest of the world, inviting them to “take part in the Palestinian national liberation movement” and to “join Palestinians in a common fight to liberate Palestine and establish a democratic state.” The front did in fact embark on dialogue with Matzpen , a small Israeli leftist organization with Trotskyite leanings, which favored the idea of setting up a binational state in Palestine.

N.B. the same source discusses that the [larger] PLO was (even on paper) much more ambiguous about the nature of the state it sought established.
FWTW, the 1988 PLO/PNC 'Declaration of Independence', while not mentioning Jews specifically, says that

the future Palestinian state should be 'free of ethnic, religius, racial discrimination' and does not elaborate on the question of religious affiliation or the role of Islamic law in a future Palestinian state.

Full text translated to English here on the UN site, with a translation corrigendum as well. OTOH one has to keep in mind that the same document says that '[t]he State of Palestine shall be an Arab State'. But that's in a sense part of the original sin of the "adoption of General Assembly resolution 181 (II) of 1947, which partitioned Palestine into an Arab and a Jewish State", in the view of the PLO (authors of that declaration). The same document finds it necessary to use phrases like 'Palestinian Arab people' (repeatedly) to make the distinction whose independence they are declaring.
TBH, I'm not sure why the first source I found is eliding some earlier Fatah declarations of a similar nature, because these also exist:

One of the strengths of Fatah and PLO was the secular message. Fatah’s ‘Seven
Points’, passed by the Central Committee of Fatah in January 1969, points to the
role of the struggle in the fight for an independent and democratic state: ‘Fatah,
the Palestinian National Liberation Movement, solemnly proclaims that the final
objective of its struggle is the restoration of the independent, democratic State of
Palestine, all of whose citizens will enjoy equal rights irrespective of their religion’ (Fatah 1969: Article 5). The vision of the future Palestinian state, as stated
above in Article 5, was a democratic state embracing the freedom of religion. In
an interview in August 1969, Yasir Arafat defines the aim of the struggle in
similar terms: ‘. . . an independent, progressive, democratic State in Palestine,
which guarantees equal rights to all its citizens, regardless of race or religion’
(Arafat 1969: 136).

But then there's the realpolitik angle that gave the Fatah/PLO the broadest support by not talking about that equality much, let alone [about] secularism...

In 1968, Salah Khalaf (Abu Iyad) suggested the formulation of the ultimate
goal of the Palestinian struggle being ‘a democratic and secular state’. His idea
was rejected by the Fatah mainstream and the PLO, since it implied equality for
Jews, a contested issue within the ranks of PLO (Kimmerling and Migdal 2003:
317). By focusing on the struggle for independence and leaving the question of
religion aside, the leadership avoided an internal division along the religious/secular, as well as Muslim/Christian, cleavages. Instead, the national narrative
allowed for Yasir Arafat and the Palestinian leadership to gain widespread
support from large and diverse sections of the Palestinian population, including
traditional elites, conservative Islamists and radical left-wingers. Also, the leftist
fraction, PFLP and DFLP, for whom the struggle for Palestine was first and foremost a class struggle, accepted Arafat’s version of the national struggle (Lindholm Schulz 1999: 32–3, 121–5; Sayigh 1997).

And then, despite PLO's attempt to be ambiguous about this, Hamas and the Islamic Jihad directly charged it with the fatal sin of aiming for a secular state, e.g. in the 1988 Covenant of Hamas Hamas, article 27.
If you somehow need more similar quotes from other speeches (similar to the 'Declaration of Independence'):

In his speech upon his return to Gaza on 1 July 1994, Arafat stated: ‘We want to build our homeland as free men, a homeland of democracy, freedom and equality’ (Arafat, quoted in Sosebee 1994: 19).

(Same source/book -- Political Leadership, Nascent Statehood and Democracy: A comparative study by  Möller & Schierenbeck, 2014)
FWTW, the PLO & Fatah advertised the membership of a few Jews or at least 'person[s] of Jewish origin' to use The Guardian's wording in their ranks. They seem to be too few for any official demographic statistics though.
Even more 'FWTW', the 2017 'revised Hamas manifesto' adds a fig leaf of their own, as it

attempted to distinguish between Jews or Judaism and modern Zionism. Hamas said that its fight was against the “racist, aggressive, colonial and expansionist” Zionist project, Israel, but not against Judaism or Jews. The updated platform also lacked some of the anti-Semitic language of the 1988 charter. [...]

[16:] Hamas affirms that its conflict is with the Zionist project not with the Jews because of their religion. Hamas does not wage a struggle against the Jews because they are Jewish but wages a struggle against the Zionists who occupy Palestine. Yet, it is the Zionists who constantly identify Judaism and the Jews with their own colonial project and illegal entity.
[17:] Hamas rejects the persecution of any human being or the undermining of his or her rights on nationalist, religious or sectarian grounds.  [...]


Now generally speaking, I'm not sure how much Hamas talks about human rights, as they don't seem to use the term as such (while rejecting 'persecution' of Jews). And the document doesn't mention citizenship either, but does mention democracy


[28:] Hamas believes in, and adheres to, managing its Palestinian relations on the basis of pluralism, democracy, national partnership, acceptance of the other and the adoption of dialogue.


The degree of credibility of these statements is another matter, of course.

the claim that Smotrich's claim is 'credible' hinges on ignoring much else he said Can you provide specific sources? Direct quotes, with links to the original? Otherwise you get stuff like this.

This answer is partially what I was looking for (only partially, because -- as it acknowledges -- the Palestinian statements lack any sort of credibility or practical implementation). But as I don't speak or write Arabic, and am not conversant with Palestinian official statements or formal writings, I'm no expert. But I disagree that parallel Israeli statements - and therefore all such statements - must be propaganda/rhetoric; IMO Israel is making an honest, good-faith effort when not limited by other constraints.

I don't agree with the premise of this question. This is just Israeli propaganda.
The point is whilst Israel is a regional power, the Palestinians have nothing. In fact, less than nothing: several reputable human rights organisations, Israeli ones amongst them, have come out and said that there is a de facto regime of Apartheid in Israel-Palestine.
Furthermore Israel has plausibly committed genocide in its retaliation for the Oct 7th raid with a pending arrest warrant by the ICC for Netanyahu and his defence monister, Goav.
This just shreds any talk of how Israel extends rights to Palestine and Palestinians. It's one reason why Palestinians demand self-determination.

This doesn't answer the question of whether Palestine has committed to granting full civil rights for Jewish citizens, and does not constitute a frame challenge answer either. I don't disagree with you, but it's completely irrelevant to what's being asked here.

"The point is whilst Israel is a regional power, the Palestinians have nothing. In fact, less than nothing" When Jews had nothing and Arabs/Muslim had everything, Muslims were "of course, the masters in every respect...Nothing equals the misery and the sufferings of the Jews at Jerusalem, inhabiting the most filthy quarter of the town, called hareth-el-yahoud, the quarter of dirt, ... – the constant objects of Mussulman oppression and intolerance". Source.

The "reputable human rights organizations" have an axe to grind. For example, the Amnesty apartheid report conflates between the Arabs/Palestinians with Israeli citizenship, who enjoy full rights and equality under law and (generally) de facto; and Palestinians under PA or Hamas control, whose rights are to be assured by the PA or Hamas. To get an idea of how skewed these organizations can be, take the Eli Yishai misquote as an example.

plausibly committed genocide If your source is the ICJ ruling, former ICJ President Joan Donoghue clarified that the court ruled Palestinians had a right to be protected from genocide, and South Africa had a right to bring their case, but not that Israel was plausibly committing genocide. Source at 5:00.

The silliness of the ICC accusation can be easily demonstrated by facts on the ground, which indicate that there is no famine in Gaza; meat, chicken and fresh vegetables are all available, if at a slightly higher price than pre-war levels. Source
